# How to check if a set of results exactly match any list of strings in a list in python

Tags: python, list

as the title says I am trying to get a exact match from any list of strings in a lists. I'm finding it hard to explain so ill show code now.

```
List = [['BOB','27','male'],['SUE','32','female'],['TOM','28','unsure']]
```

This would be an example of the lists layout, then i want to send information through from a web scrape to see if anything matches any of the item[0]+item[1]+item[2] in the list, the problem i am having is that the web scrape is using a for argument:-

```
HTML = requests.get(url).content
match = re.compile('Name"(.+?)".+?Age"(.+?)".+?Sex"(.+?)"').findall(HTML)
for name,age,sex in match:
```

Then my next part also using a for argument:-

```
    for item in List:
        if item[0] == name and item[1] == age and item[2] == sex:
            pass
        else:
            print 'Name = '+name
            print 'Age = '+age
            print 'Sex = '+sex
```

But obviously if the result matches any of the single sets of lists it cannot match the other 2 so it will not pass, is there a way i can achieve it to check to see if it matches anything set of 3 results in the list name,age,and sex being item[0],item[1],item[2] exactly? I have also tried:

```
if all(item[0] == name and item[1] == age and item[2] == sex for item in List):
    pass
```

This does not work, I'm assuming its because its not a direct match in all the lists of list and if i change all to any i get results coming back that skip if any of the strings match, ie age is 27,32 or 28. I know my regex is poor form and not the ideal way to parse HTML but its all I can use confidently at the moment sorry. Full code below for easier reading.

```
List = [['BOB','27','male'],['SUE','32','female'],['TOM','28','unsure']]
HTML = requests.get(url).content
match = re.compile('Name"(.+?)".+?Age"(.+?)".+?Sex"(.+?)"').findall(HTML)
for name,age,sex in match:
    for item in List:
        if item[0] == name and item[1] == age and item[2] == sex:
            pass
        else:
            print 'Name = '+name
            print 'Age = '+age
            print 'Sex = '+sex
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, I am still a beginner and have not used forum's much so I will apologise in advance if it's not grammatically correct or I have asked in the wrong way.

Answer (score 1):

`re.findall` returns tuples, so you can simplify the comparison if the items in your list match the return type:

```
import re

# Changed sub-lists to tuples.
items = [('BOB','27','male'),('SUE','32','female'),('TOM','28','unsure')]

html = '''\
Name"BOB" Age"27" Sex"male"
Name"PAT" Age"19" Sex"unsure"
Name"SUE" Age"31" Sex"female"
Name"TOM" Age"28" Sex"unsure"
'''

for item in re.findall('Name"(.+?)".+?Age"(.+?)".+?Sex"(.+?)"', html):
    if item in items:
        name,age,sex = item
        print 'Name =', name
        print 'Age =', age
        print 'Sex =', sex
        print
```

Output:

```
Name = BOB
Age = 27
Sex = male

Name = TOM
Age = 28
Sex = unsure
```

You can also use `item not in items` if you want the ones that don't match.

Answer (score 0):

First change the name of the list. `List` is not a reserved keyword,but it's not a good practice to use abstract names. My suggestion is to make the data a list. If I understood right your question, it's a matter of getting everything differently. So:

```
for sublist in my_list:
    if (sublist[0] != weblist[0]) and (sublist[1] != weblist[1]) and (sublist[2] != weblist[2]):
        print("List is different")
```

Comment: Thank you i will change, this is pretty much what i am doing. The problem being that i only want the results if they do not match any of the results exactly as they are in list, i.e. name==item[0],age==[1],sex == item[2] so that I'll not get results for anyone called bob that's 32 and male or either of the other 2, if that makes sense?

Comment: Edited to make it look more like what you want

Comment: Will try that now, appreciate your replys

Comment: `List` is not a keyword. `list` is a built-in type, but not a reserved keyword.

Comment: @Mikael You could improve the `if` statement: `if all(sublist[i] != my_list[i] for i in range(len(sublist))):` and then the OP would not need to add anything to the `if` clause if his list gets longer!

Comment: @MarkTolonen By reserved keyword,I meant a name that's already used by Python,so you shouldn't use it.

Comment: Its not used, the lower case `list` is used. Anyway, I think we both got your point, to avoid using abstract names.

Comment: `List` is **not** already used by Python, but `list` is.  Case matters.  Reserved keywords give errors if you use them, but built-ins do not.  Semantics.  `list` is a built-in, so you do have to avoid using it, because it can be reassigned.  `for` is a reserved keyword, and will error if you use it, and can't be reassigned.  The point is, delete your first two sentences :)

Comment: It's not prohibited but it sure is a bad practice to use abstract names.